# Using WSDL files in Defining the Type of the system

Tags: wsdl, system, soa

My Qustion is:
How we can use a WSDL file describe a system, to determine whether this system is Service-based system (SOA) or not?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "SOA".

Answer (score 1):

If something provides a wsdl effectively it is providing a service of some description.  So in the theoretical world is is a SOA component.  However, whether it fits into or uses say Oracle SOA Server is irrelevant in the SOA theory because what you are really talking about is Service based architecture.

Some Oracle services for example will contain namespaces specific to Oracle systems within the wsdl and they could be used, although I don't know why you would need to care about the server system.  It is a service after all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sweetfa, What I am trying to do is the following: identify SOA-based systems among 400 running systems. Then take those SOA ones through another phase of research. That's why I am looking for a way to Identify SOA-based system, by the help of WSDL, or any other possiblity, e.g (SOA Identification framewrok) if there is any...??

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  The best bet is to try and use the namespaces in the wsdl to discern the nature of the hidden beast, although it won't give a full representation necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The system behaves as it sees fit, the WSDL is just a specification. The system maybe implements a service according to that WSDL maybe not, you can't know even after exhaustive testing since the system can easily change the behavior.

As an example: is [codepad.org](http://codepad.org) a service-based system? How would you use WSDL to check that?

Comment: Then I may reformulate my question: Is there a language, technic, framework can be used to Identify whether this system is SOA system or not?

Comment: @Zain: No, since the system might change the behavior at any time. WSDL is a contract only, not a guarantee.

Comment: Agree with you on the behavior point, but then you mean there is no approach/framework can be used to differentiate SOA systems from non-SOA systems?

Comment: @Zain: You think "SOA" has some solid formal definition like for example a "valid C program". It doesn't - "SOA" is 60% marketing buzzword and only 40% technical definition. That's why you can't formally decide whether something is SOA or not.

Comment: so right, That's why I asked that question. Actually I am trying to find an approach to identify SOA systems from those are not inside our repositry. Then do some research in the SOA ones. But if I cant define them I won't be able to complete the research.

Comment: @Zain: Use common sense. Find the system spec and look through it and decide whether it is SOA enough for your goals.

Comment: That would be efficient if you are looking at small number of systems, But in the case of 400 systems?... anyway thanks for your comments.